# Finding the fx and fy components of a point on a contour map.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, contour-integration

[image]

Any idea what they're asking for here?

Are they just asking for coordinates? If so how would I find the coordinates? My eyes are telling me point C is at (1.55,1.55) but how am I supposed to know for sure? I can hardly tell where's it at. I just know it's between 0 and 2 for both x and y. What's this question asking? What is C'?
[image]

What are the steps in solving problems like these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably $C = (1..5, 1.5)$ and $C' = (3.5, 1.5)$ that means that $|CC'| = 2.0$. Now From the scale $f(C)= -10$ and $f(C') = -15$, then
$$
f_x(C) \approx \frac{-15-(-10)}{2.0} = -5/2 = -2.5
$$

Comment: where did $C'$ come from?

Comment: It is written in the last image, move horizonrally in the direction of growing $x$, "until you meat the next level line", that is $C'$

Comment: awesome thank you

Comment: so Fy(c) is just $0$ then?

Comment: no, but follow the same steps for $f_x(C)$, just move vertically from $C$ to the next level line to find $C'$

Comment: ah okay okay thank you